# A corruption was discovered in the file system structure

Tags: windows, windows-10

We are receiving the following error in the Event Viewer > System events list. How can we resolve it?

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Ntfs" Guid="{DD70BC80-EF44-421B-8AC3-CD31DA613A4E}" /> 
    <EventID>55</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-01-07T22:20:31.481368800Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>265954</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="216" /> 
    <Channel>System</Channel> 
    <Computer>Owner-PC</Computer> 
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DriveName">D:</Data> 
    <Data Name="DeviceName" /> 
    <Data Name="CorruptionState">0x0</Data> 
    <Data Name="HeaderFlags">0x922</Data> 
    <Data Name="Severity">Critical</Data> 
    <Data Name="Origin">File System Driver</Data> 
    <Data Name="Verb">Bad FRS</Data> 
    <Data Name="Description">
      The Master File Table (MFT) contains a
      corrupted file record. The file reference number is 0x1000000000000.
      The name of the file is "<unable to determine file name>".
    </Data> 
    <Data Name="Signature">0xd070231a</Data> 
    <Data Name="Outcome">Spot Verifier Bypassed On Critical</Data> 
    <Data Name="SampleLength">0</Data> 
    <Data Name="SampleData" /> 
    <Data Name="SourceFile">0x1</Data> 
    <Data Name="SourceLine">868</Data> 
    <Data Name="SourceTag">199</Data> 
    <Data Name="CallStack">
      NTFS+0x156ec, 
      NTFS+0xd44b1, NTFS+0x1080d5, 
      NTFS+0xf313d, NTFS+0x1d5e0, 
      ntoskrnl+0x79dd9, ntoskrnl+0xe7758, 
      ntoskrnl+0x1545b6
    </Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

## What have we tried?

### Basic SMART

```
> wmic
wmic:root\cli> diskdrive get status
Status
OK
OK
```

### Check NTFS

```
>chkntfs D:
Cannot query state of drive D:
```

### Check Disk

```
>chkdsk /r D:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Data.
```

#### Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

```
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 0.
18432 file records processed.
File verification completed.
0 large file records processed.
0 bad file records processed.
```

#### Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

```
Deleting index entry B52E4F3-E870-4CF0-95DE-BC84F8721C11} in index $I30 of file
3220.
Deleting index entry 61D8746-7DE9-4160-AA8C-712F086F1D13} in index $I30 of file
3224.
Deleting index entry 34ABE3C-99F7-4A32-A0B1-0A4F8ECA4CB1} in index $I30 of file
3226.
Deleting index entry 6C074EF-EC95-47FC-A873-E79AC5BFFD80} in index $I30 of file
3226.
Deleting index entry 6C7D634-34EE-402E-A6F9-C86809B35313} in index $I30 of file
3226.
Deleting index entry 5E7DBB4-CDB5-42F9-B99B-78A05A5933CE} in index $I30 of file
3230.
Deleting index entry E58B84A-F827-49D7-82BD-DEA0621246BE} in index $I30 of file
3238.
Deleting index entry 76BD55E-43F6-4A50-878D-EF6CA6AA8090} in index $I30 of file
3241.
Deleting index entry 8597F17-F5F5-4798-BA94-DCCD02AD0F2F} in index $I30 of file
3243.
Deleting index entry 588F616-0C9B-450B-A3AD-B26E26BDB3E3} in index $I30 of file
3245.
Deleting index entry 5E6C666-0D25-4A4F-971E-DEE25265C838} in index $I30 of file
3256.
Deleting index entry 57BC54D-5DAB-462C-AC42-53E6A736BF19} in index $I30 of file
3266.
18610 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
0 unindexed files scanned.
0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
```

#### Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...

```
Security descriptor verification completed.
Inserting data attribute into file 0.
91 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.
```

#### Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...

```
18416 files processed.    
File data verification completed.
```

#### Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...

```
Progress: 11010064 of 442093830 done; Stage:  2%; Total:  3%; ETA:   3:06:48 ...
```

Comment: Replace the HDD

Comment: What leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: Try `chkdsk d: /f`

Comment: start by checking the SMART stats on the disk to confirm it is mechanically healthy. Then if it is, run `chkntfs <driveletter>:`on it. if the message says so, run `chkdsk /r <driveletter>:`. If the chkntfs says there is no corruption, then the event was triggered by a failed IO request, and may not be a big deal (in which case ignore it). see here for EventID 55 info: https://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2.3790.1830&EvtID=55&EvtSrc=ntfs&LCID=1033 Note that if you have reallocated sectors, ramhound is probably right.

Comment: A healthy drive does not have file system problems

Comment: @FrankThomas SMART says that `D:` is okay. `chkntfs D:` says that that it `Cannot query the start of drive D:`.

Comment: reboot and try again. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms831841.aspx Obligatory - "have you tried turning it off and back on again?"

Comment: When it completes, use a tool like Speedfan or whatever to view the individual smart stats. in particular, check Reallocated Sector Count, Current Pending Sector count, and Raw Read Error Rate. if they are low, check them again tommorow, and if they have increased at all, replace the disk. if they are high (more than you can count on your fingers), replace the disk. repeat in one week. a few bad blocks and read error are not necessarily fatal issues, but bad blocks tend to increase exponentially to time (eg once you start falling, you fall faster and faster...). and ramhound's point is valid.

Comment: i noticed that error on a virtual machine ... so a virtual vmware disk.