# Windows 10 Event ID 55 - "A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume ??"

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ntfs, smart

I've changed my harddisk 2 or 3 months ago after my old harddisk became unreadable without noticing me. (I was expecting at least slowness, or a Windows warning etc. None happened. I was using computer one day, computer freezed, then never opened. I changed the hdd, it was working.)

Anyway, while I was looking for another event in the Windows Event Viewer, I've noticed this. Windows 10 Event ID 55 - "A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume ??"

[The description of the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAQnf.jpg)

I did chkdsk c: and everything seems ok.

When I checked this question [A corruption was discovered in the file system structure](https://superuser.com/questions/1023242/a-corruption-was-discovered-in-the-file-system-structure), people said to look at S.M.A.R.T. features. I looked it up with CrystalDiskInfo, and it looks normal to me. But I don't know anything about HDD's so I'm not sure.

[The S.M.A.R.T. features.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMZFo.jpg)

There are other Ntfs(Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs) events with ID 98, before and after this event, and all of them is like: `Volume C: (\Device\HarddiskVolume4) is healthy.  No action is needed.`

Should I worry, or is it because an I/O error as stated in the other question's comments (I can't link the Microsoft page about Event ID 55 due to my new account, but the link is in the other question, and the page says :

```
The file system on the volume might be corrupt due to one or more of the following reasons:

The disk might have bad sectors.
I/O requests issued by the file system to the disk subsystem might not have been completed successfully.
```

If it is going to fail like my old HDD, I would like to replace it. But if it's not an HDD error and the HDD is OK, I won't replace it.

Comment: If Windows has discovered a disk that is about to fail, then you have a disk thats about to fail, you just have to discover which disk the volumes belongs to.

Comment: Windows has discovered a disk that is about to fail in this scenario ? I only have one disk.

Comment: try `chkdsk -r` to do a full scan of the disk. As for your SMART stats, your reallocated sector and current pending sector counts are both good, so if it does have bad sectors, it hasn't noticed them yet. check the SMART stats after the job completes (and it will take quite a while; do not abort midway). Its worrisome that the error log does not indicate the disk in question.

Comment: @FrankThomas why it is worrisome ? (I have only one disk.)

Comment: because we may be looking at the health of the wrong disk. the bad message might be related to removable media, or built in storage that you don't know that you have. The contradiction between your statements on the 55 error and the 98 errors indicates some kind of confusion somewhere.

Comment: I didn't have removable media inserted at that time. And as far as I know there is no built-in storage other than I replaced in this laptop. The disk I am using is SSHD, http://www.seagate.com/consumer/upgrade/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/ (ST500LM000) Could it be because of the 'SSD' part of the disk ?

Comment: I did the chkdsk /r and after that the S.M.A.R.T features changed as follow: Read Error Rate Old: 113 New: 111 Spin-Up Time Old: 99 New: 98 Airflow temperature and temperature changed(normal, I guess?)

Comment: That is all normal. SMART stats are not all created equal. some indicate that its a little warm in your room this evening, and others indicate permanent critical failures. Sounds like your disk surface is healthy, and at a glance the seek and raw read error rates seem reasonable. sounds like a healthy disk.

Comment: So how can we explain that Event 55 under the light of these?